# SF5 - Deprecation from 5.0 to 5.2

Tags: symfony, deprecated

I am in the process of migrating my project from SF5.0.8 to SF5.2.5 the latest version of symfony.

I have settled all depreciations except 1:

***User Deprecated: The "Doctrine \ Common \ Inflector \ Inflector :: classify" method is deprecated and will be dropped in doctrine / inflector 2.0. Please update to the new Inflector API.***

This depreciation occurs every time I use FindBy ... on a repository.
Do you know how to settle this depreciation?

Thank you

Comment: I made a quick test using a fresh 5.2.5 installation and I see no evidence of this depreciation.  Even checked the vendor/...Inflector.php file and there are no depreciation that I can see.  Did you originally upgrade from a 4.x application? Maybe try to reproduce in a new 5.2.5 project and then compare your composer.json files. 'composer show doctrine/inflector' yields a version of 2.0.3.

Comment: I need version 2.1.0 of orm-pack (version 2.8 of doctrine), which requires sensio / framework-extra-bundle with at least version 5.6 itself it seems incompatible with my version of the google charts. I think the problem is there. If you don't have the problem it's because your update must have put you a 2.8 version of doctrine (see vendor / doctrine / orm / readme.md)

Comment: My version of doctrine/orm happens to be 2.8.2.  The framework extra bundle shows as 5.6.1.  I did create the project using PHP 8.0 but I would not think that would make a differemce.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by upgrading sensio framework to version 5.6.1 then orm-pack to version 2.1.0.
By appropriate modification of composer.json then composer update. I have broken down each of its version upgrades. When I do both at the same time I can't do it !!

Comment: My go to method in these sorts of cases is to simply create a new project, load all the extra dependencies and then replace the existing composer.json file with the new one.  Composer is great but sometimes everything seems to blow up.

Comment: Yes...but in my project i have others dependencies that are not in a new project => for example, i have added google charts and a fews others

Comment: That is where the "load all extra dependencies come in".  Use composer require as necessary.